# What is a protein interface account?

Tags: biochemistry

I'm not a specialist but I'd like to get into meaning of what is written in some articles. In the sentences:

> "The large numbers of salt bridges and hydrogen bonds in the protein
> interface account ..."
>
> "Alanine scanning mutagenesis have showed that only some of the amino
> acids of the interface account ..."

what is "account" stands for? As long as I understand, an "interface" is a protein part/domain that contacts with another interacting protein. But what is an "interface account"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a not about chemical nomenclature, but common word.

Comment: *Account* seems to be used as a verb here, but I can't tell without more context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["Account" in this case is used as a verb.](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/account%20for%20(something))

The original paper for the second quote [appears to be a PLoS One article](https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0094745), and the exact quote is

> Alanine scanning mutagenesis have showed that only some of the amino
>   acids of the interface account for the binding free energy.

We could equivalent rewrite this as

> Alanine scanning mutagenesis have showed that only some of the amino
>   acids of the interface **are responsible for** the binding free energy

or

> Alanine scanning mutagenesis have showed that only some of the amino
>   acids of the interface **contribute significantly to** the binding free energy

I haven't looked at the first quote, but I suspect it's in a similar boat.

Comment: It does make sense. Thank you for the answer.